# How to call multiple functions from "change" attribute in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i need to call two functions at same time from change attribute in input checkbox component.

I have two function, one is generic(Say SaveFunction) and another function(do some calculation). i tried one way as binding expression such

```
{!c.saveFunction + c.calculateOpptyValue}
```

the above code didnt work and i know another workaround calling another help in generic function , but i dont want implement any unnecessary logic in generic function.

Please let me know how can i do first way in calling the multiple functions.

Comment: I don't think, we can do it.

Comment: Using helper is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `c.calculateOpptyValue` from the `c.saveFunction` funtion
Example:

```
c.saveFunction(){
  console.log('===');
  calculateOpptyValue(); //Call functions here
}
```

Comment: My question is different here,  i am using  same c.savefunction for multiple components , but i want c.calculateOpptyValue for only one component. so as per your logic it call for all components events wherever i used autosave function, rather than i need use calculateOpptyValue function only one component along with savefunction.

Comment: You can handle that using some boolean variable as when to call the function.

Comment: Or use two handlers

Comment: Option 1: Use the reverse of Krishna's approach and call saveFunction from calculateOpptyValue.  Option 2: Put functions you want to reuse in the helper, and use the controller exclusively for handling events.

Comment: @Raj_SFDC let us know if this was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend the idea of @Krishna Bidwai ,
If you need to call c.calculateOpptyValue from  c.savefunction for only one button, below approach can be used :

On your button add a div with an attribute such as

```
<div onclick="{!c.savefunction }" data-value="abc">
    <lightning:button label="Save" iconPosition="left" value="123"/>
</div>
```

in your controller function :

```
   savefunction  : function(component, event, helper) {
        var currentEvt = event.currentTarget;
        var data_Value = currentEvt.dataset.value;
        console.log(data_Value);
    if(data_Value == 'abc'){
    calculateOpptyValue();
    }
}
```

For more information on above technique , refer below answer from @Caspar Harmer:
[What is the correct way to pass Parameters to Lightning JS controller from UI:Button?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171852/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pass-parameters-to-lightning-js-controller-from-uibu)