# What is the correct way to pass Parameters to Lightning JS controller from UI:Button?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, parameters, ui

I have a button in a table in lightning component. I'm trying to get clicked id of the record.

**Component markup**

```
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--fixed-layout">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Remove">Remove</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.Items}" var="item">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!item.Name}">{!item.Name}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form onclick="{!c.removeItem}">
                            <input type="hidden" class="prodclass" value="{!item.Id}" id="{!item.Id}"  />
                            <lightning:button label="Remove" iconName="utility:delete" iconPosition="left" variant="destructive" value="{!item.Id}"/>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS Controller**

```
removeItem: function(component, event, helper) {

    var id_str = event.target.getElementsByClassName('prodclass')[0].value;

    console.log(id_str);

}
```

I'm getting error,

> ElementsByClassName is not a function

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('prodclass')[0].value returns the value, so the issue is not with getElementsByClassName are you sure you are sharing all your code, why are you using event.target? can you share your event, if any?

Comment: @glls Thanks. it's a simple button call. No event involved. I'm trying to get event's parameters to read the current record Id.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no need for a `form` in your `td`.

Wrap your `button` in a `div`, attach the value to the `div` via a `data-` attribute and grab it from the `event.currentTarget`. Eg:

```
<div onclick="{!c.removeItem}" data-value="123">
    <lightning:button label="Remove" iconName="utility:delete" iconPosition="left"  variant="destructive" value="123"/>
</div>
```

Controller method:

```
removeItem: function(component, event, helper) {
    var ctarget = event.currentTarget;
    var id_str = ctarget.dataset.value;
    console.log(id_str);
}
```

Comment: An additional point is that for `data-stageName="123"` you might expect `ctarget.dataset.stageName` to work. But the name gets mapped to lowercase so it has to be `ctarget.dataset.stagename`. So best to avoid camel-casing in the name.

Answer (score 6):

I think currently recommended by Salesforce way of passing parameters from button to controller is by using `event.getSource()`. Please note it will work only on Lightning components (for example on `lightning:button` and not on standard HTML `<button>`. For HTML components use `event.currentTarget` as in other answer) Please consider following example:

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="colours" type="String[]" default="['red', 'green', 'blue']"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.colours}" var="col">
    <lightning:button label="{!'Colour ' + col}" value="{!col}" onclick="{!c.onBtnColourClick}"/><br/>
</aura:iteration>
```

**Controller**

```
onBtnColourClick: function(component, event, helper) {
    var msg = event.getSource().get('v.value');
    //do something with value
    component.set('v.message', msg);
},
```

This is especially useful in cases like when you need to make a table in which every row has individual button (let's say Delete the record from this row). We have to pass somehow the `recordId` of record in specific row.

For `lightning:button` component, you can use `name` and `value` attributes to assign value from iterated object.

**WARNING:**
Please note that as time of writing you cannot generate `aura:id` dynamically, so in the example above writing `aura:id="{!col}"` and using `event.getSource().getLocalId()` in controller would give you literally `'{!col}'` string!

Answer (score 5):

The alternative method is to define a new custom component for a row in the table. Make that component have Item as an attribute, then you can read it in the event handler.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Item__c" />
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!item.Name}">{!item.Name}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <lightning:button label="Remove" iconName="utility:delete" iconPosition="left" variant="destructive" onclick="{!c.removeItem}" value="{!item.Id}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</aura:component>
```

Then the controller for this component would include:

```
removeItem: function(component, event, helper) {
    var id_str = component.get('v.item').Id;
    console.log(id_str);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice clean way to do it.